# What "elaborate game" is being played with the Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

At the end of Age of Ultron, Thor says that

> the Mind Stone is the fourth of the infinity stones that has surfaced in recent years.  Thor says that "someone has been playing an elaborate game and making pawns of us all."

We know Thanos is involved, but what is a more thorough explanation?  It seems that:

- The Space Stone was housed in the Tesseract and showed up in Captain America: The First Avenger, where it was used by HYDRA. It reappeared in the first Avengers movie, and

  > ended up being taken back to Asgard by Thor.
- The Reality Stone showed up in Thor: The Dark World and was

  > entrusted to the Collector.
- The Power Stone showed up in Guardians of the Galaxy, where it was sought by Thano

  > but ended up with Nova Corps.
- The Mind Stone is given to Loki by Thanos before in the first Avengers movie, and then

  > goes to HYDRA before Age of Ultron (foreshadowed by a teaser at the end of Winter Soldier), and ends up embedded in the forehead of The Vision.

**What elaborate game is being played, and who is playing it?**

Comment: [Parcheesi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi). It’s parcheesi.

Comment: Someone's flushing the good guys into tracking down the remaining stones - I mean, how obvious could Thor make it? _When water blackens in the well 
Three Swords^W^WFive Stones must come again._

Comment: Spoilers: http://www.amazon.com/Infinity-Gauntlet-Jim-Starlin/dp/0785156593

Comment: @CodeMed: the thing is, there’s nothing particularly obscure or difficult-to-understand in what we’ve seen so far in the MCU. The movies haven’t laid out the plan in a mysterious way: they just haven’t laid it out yet. So even explanation of what happens with this character in the comics is speculation, because the movies won’t necessarily follow any of it.

Answer (score 2):

As of yet, we have no idea. You’ve summed up all the information we have so far.

Marvel has [announced that the next Avengers movie will be called *Infinity War*](http://screenrant.com/avengers-3-4-infinity-war-release-dates/) and will be released in two parts in 2018 and 2019.

So, ask again after that comes out, if you still need to.

Comment: @CodeMed: that’s true. Hey, you should add an answer mentioning the post-credits scene. I’m not sure the comics are worth wibbling on about though. The *Age of Ultron* comics wouldn’t have been particularly helpful to people wanting to know what was going to happen in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.